# Why is the background color of my DIV element not visible?

Tags: html, css, row, background-color

```css
/**This code doesnt change the color of the class row1**/

html, body {
  font-family :'montserrat',sans-serif;
  }
h1 {
  border-left  : 2px solid #00f28f;
  font-size    : 48px;
  font-weight  : 400;
  padding-left : 20px;
  }
.main {
  margin-top : 80px;
  }
form input {
  background : #F0f0f0;
  border     : none;
  font-size  : 36px;
  padding    : 20px;
  width      : 100%;
  transition : background 0s, border-left 0s;
  }
form input:focus {
  background  : #fff;
  border-left : 2pxsolid #000;
  box-shadow  : none;
  outline     : none;
  }
button.button {
  background : transparent;
  border     : none;
  color      : #00f2bf;
  cursor     : pointer;
  font-size  : 36px;
  padding    : 20px 24px;
  transition : background 0s, border-left 0s;
  }
button.button:hover {
  background : #00f2bf;
  color      :  #fff;
  }
.row1 {
  background : yellowgreen;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?preview.size=20" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\kalyanasundar.s\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\proj\proj.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <h1>Kalyan The Coder</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="row1">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
          <input type="text" id="TextBox1" placeholder="Enter your query">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
          <button type="submit" class="button">post</button>
        </div>
```

This command works fine except that the row1 color doesn't change and not sure why.
If I change row1 to row on CSS, the color of header changes. I am not sure how to change the class in the CSS style sheet.
I am beginner and would like to explore more on this.

Comment: no, this is quite normal, imaginary commands always do anything

Comment: What @MisterJojo is trying to say is welcome to Stack Overflow! We unfortunately need to see your code in order to be of any assistance. As it stands currently, your question is likely to be closed as "needs improvement".

Comment: With that edit, you're getting warmer! Now, *why* should we expect the color of `row1` to change? I understand we can infer it from your code, but why do *you* believe it should? Is this just the desired effect and it's not working?

Comment: There is a class in html called row1. There is a reference to that class in css sheet. Now row1 has to be yellow green is what i have asked for. Thats the reason

Comment: `use class="row row1` follow the bootstrap rules

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to give your element height.

---

It helps to simplify the problem. Currently, if you add `height: 100px` to your `row1` class, the background becomes a visible `yellowgreen` as you desire:

```
.row1 {
    background: yellowgreen;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Let's show the difference with a simplified snippet:

```css
.row-1 { background-color: yellowgreen; }
.row-2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-1"></div>
<div class="row-2"></div>
```

Notice how you can't see `row-1` here? Adding a height, padding, or anything else that expands the `div`'s area will make it show:

```css
.row-1 { background-color: yellowgreen; }
```

```html
<div class="row-1">
  <p>This should make the row visible.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Taco. I would be grateful to you for this kind gesture. Happy to learn it from you. This help in understanding the code mean a lot in my career in coding. :-)

Comment: Also, when I add a class ".row" and add color to it without mentioning height, It works. Why do i need to add height for one row alone ?

Comment: @KalyanSundar As I mentioned, a `div` has no height by default. Without height you're not going to see the background color.

Comment: SOrry to bother you again. Like you said div doesnt have a height. In the same snippet, I have a class called as row where I add color without mentioning height. does it work because its in the header?

Comment: @KalyanSundar no, as I mentioned before; it shows color because it has *content*.